# Add multiple numbers in a single cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How do I add multiple numbers in a cell across a row?
I successfully used this formula to add multiple numbers in a single cell SUM(SPLIT(C3,",")).
But now I need to sum all the cells in the same row.

[image]

like this - where the total should be 185

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(JOIN(",",C3:3),","))
```

#### Breakdown

1. We first `JOIN` everything together with a comma.
2. `SPLIT` then puts each value into their own cells.
3. Then finally, `SUM` Everything up.